# Using Haskell to interpret multi-line strings of code at runtime

Tags: haskell, hint

#### Problem:

I would like to be able to interpret any sort of Haskell code at runtime - also code that is not bound by a single line.

Right now I am using [hint](https://github.com/haskell-hint/hint) to do this below, which works with single lines:

```hs
html :: String -> IO String
html code = do    
    r <- runInterpreter $ do
        setImports ["Prelude"]
        interpret code (as :: () -> String)

    case r of
        Left err -> return $ show err
        Right func -> return $ func()
```

#### Example:

If `code` from above is `\() -> "Hello World"` that works.

But if `code` is something like this below, <strike>my code from above does not work</strike>: (**Update**: it does).

```hs
\() -> let concatString :: String -> String -> String
           concatString str1 str2 = str1 ++ str2
       in concatString "Hello" "World"
```

#### Question:

How do I interpret multi-line Haskell strings at runtime using hint or any other library?

---

## Update

This does work - I made a mistake in the original expression (which I have now corrected).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used hint, but I can tell you that your example is not a valid Haskell expression. `where` clauses are not attached to expressions, they are attached to *definitions*.  That is, you have to have an `=` sign to be able to have a `where` clause.

```
-- Correct
foo = bar
    where
    bar = baz
        where 
        baz = 42

-- Incorrect
foo = (bar + 1 where bar = 41)
```

If you want to define something in expression context you must use `let`

```
let concatString :: String -> String -> String
    concatString str1 str2 = str1 ++ str2
in concatString "Hello" "World"
```

Comment: You're right! And that was also the issue, using the let statement works, also with multi-lines. Amazing! Is there no way to attach definitions to expressions in Haskell?

Comment: There is, and it's `let`.   `let` : expression :: `where` : definition.  You can even put a `where` clause after a definition you make in `let` (I think)